# Why won't my large, SSRS-generated excel (XLSX) file open?

Tags: excel, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I have an Excel (XLSX) file generated from SSRS (SQL Server 2014) that contains about 650k rows and is approximately 120MB in size. It takes about 8 hours to open and when it finally does open, everything is blank. Is there a limit to the size of an Excel file, or even an Excel file generated by SSRS?

Comment: try saving it as a csv and open that.

Comment: This is coming from a subscription. I'm not able to save it as a csv.

Comment: XLSX has a maximum row limit of 1,000,000 rows as far as I know. If tere is a lot of formatting that would slow things down but 8 hours to open is not right. I open files with 500K rows in and they open in a minute, 90 seconds at the most. Are you sure your PC is not simply running out of memory?